# NAs introduced by coercion with plot function R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot my data with the Year-Month on x-axis and the Temperature on y-axis. I've got some years where I don't have any data available, therefore NAs. When I plot the data I get the error message "NAs introduced by coercion". I did the same thing with another data (also with NAs) before and it worked, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Year_month Temperature
1937-04 NA
1937-05 NA 
1937-06 NA 
1937-07 NA
1938-04 -2.3
1938-05 11.8
1938-06 2.5
1938-07 -1.2
1939-04 NA
1939-05 NA
1939-06 NA
1939-07 NA
1940-04 -2.3
1940-05 -9.3
1940-06 8.5
1940-07 5.6
")  



df$Year_Month <- format(df$Year_Month,format ="%Y-%m")


plot(df$Year_Month, df$Temperature, type="l", col="red", lwd=2,
     xlab="Jahr", ylab="Durchschnittstemperatur [°C]", ylim=c(-10,15), xlim=c(1930,1940))
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `plot(Temperature ~ Year_Month, data=df[complete.cases(df),], ...)`?

Comment: Funktioniert leider auch nicht, gleiche Error Message

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually your data. Your attempt to create dates out of the year-months failed somewhat. You can't `format` a string and probably meant to format a date.

Let's do this first by `paste`ing `"-01"` for the first of each month to the `"Year_Month"` and create a date column.

```
df <- transform(df, Date=as.Date(paste0(Year_Month, '-01')))
```

Now, R correctly can identify dates in the new column due to the appropriate `"Date"` class. It uses the respective `plot` method, and it works.

```
plot(Temperature ~ Date, df, col="red", lwd=2, ylim=c(-10, 15), 
     xlab="Jahr", ylab="Durchschnittstemperatur [°C]")
```

[image]

**However**, you probably want the year-months as x-labels. We can't take the `"Year_Month"` column since it has gaps, so we make `seq`uences out of minimum and maximum date, i.e `range` and increase by `"month"`. Since this sequence will also be of class `"Date"`, they are correctly assigned to the appropriate date. For sake of a clean axis we may want to subset on every 5th label only, which we may do with modulo `%% 5`.

```
dat_sq <- do.call(seq, c(as.list(range(df$Date)), 'month'))
dat_5 <- (seq_along(dat_sq) + 4) %% 5 == 0

plot(Temperature ~ Date, df, col="red", lwd=2, ylim=c(-10, 15), 
     xlab="Jahr", ylab="Durchschnittstemperatur [°C]", xaxt='n')
axis(1, dat_sq, labels=FALSE)
mtext(substr(dat_sq, 1, 7)[dat_5], 1, 1, at=dat_sq[dat_5], cex=.9)
```

[image]

Looks more informative.

Lots of new commands, but you will adapt :)

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(Year_Month = c("1937-04", "1937-05", "1937-06", 
"1937-07", "1938-04", "1938-05", "1938-06", "1938-07", "1939-04", 
"1939-05", "1939-06", "1939-07", "1940-04", "1940-05", "1940-06", 
"1940-07"), Temperature = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, -2.3, 11.8, 2.5, 
-1.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, -2.3, -9.3, 8.5, 5.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: Thank you, that works!
But is there also a possibility to include the years that have NAs and have R just not put a dot there? It would be interesting to show that these years have been included in the data, but don't have any data...

Comment: @natash Please see updated answer.